# Можно ли в Intellij Idea подсвечивать измененные модули?

Tags: intellij-idea

Как сделать в idea так, чтобы подсвечивались не только измененные файлы (относительно гита), но и вся иерархия до него (пакеты, модули)?

Такое есть в eclipse, думаю, что в idea тоже должно быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно. Используйте чекбокс в *Settings*:

> Version Control -> Confirmation -> Highligh directories that contain
> modified files in the Project tree